# Cosets form a group if normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, theorem-provers

Given a group **G** and its subgroup **H** that creates cosets, prove that cosets form a group *iff **H** - is a normal subgroup.*
I've tried to find any good prove but I failed - most of the sources (including ProveWiki) provide this statement "as is" and other sources provide incorrect proves like here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYKdh5oQ4Zw&list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6&index=9&t=502s

6:54 - brackets are opened as the operation is commutative - but in fact, it not necessarily true.

---

Can you, please, tell why there's a huge leap between statement that

**product of two elements from two cosets must be contained by the third coset and this operation should be associative
<=> 
subgroup ability to form up equal left and right cosets.**

Or give me, please, prove of the statement, I'll try to understand the leap.

Comment: Do you know why we talk about well definedness?

Comment: Sorry to close your first question, but this has been asked before and I wrote a pretty comprehensive answer to it.